# Elasticsearch: could not find java in bundled jdk at .../jdk/bin/java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

When I try to run .bin/elasticsearch, I get the following error:

> could not find java in bundled jdk at /home/ubuntu/Elastic
> Search/elasticsearch-7.8.0/jdk/bin/java

I have absolutely no idea what's going on. I know this topic has been created before, but I haven't found a way to fix. For `java -version` I get:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> **The most probable reason for the above error is that `JAVA_HOME` is not set**

1. To display `JAVA_HOME` variable path, run this command `echo $JAVA_HOME`

If nothing appears then follow the below steps:

2. To see all the java versions installed in Ubuntu, use this command:

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

3. Set your java path using this. - `export JAVA_HOME=<YOUR-JAVA-PATH>`

Comment: For macos running `/usr/libexec/java_home` gives you the **java path**, which then needs to be set as `JAVA_HOME` variable via the **CLI**

Comment: It really helpful. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem on linux, when I was running elasticsearch using

```
sh elasticsearch
```

I got the error

```
Elasticsearch: could not find java in bundled jdk at .../jdk/bin/java
```

Then I referred to the official [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html)
and set **ES_JAVA_HOME** environment variable.

After running elasticsearch again, I got the following message and it ran successfully

```
ignoring JAVA_HOME=/project/jdkForElasticSearch/; using ES_JAVA_HOME
```

**Note:** After setting environment variable, restart your terminal to reflect the updated value in it.

Answer (score -1):

i was also getting the same error and all i have to do is -

1. check if already have JAVA_HOME set as ENV variable ? if yes, remove it and simply run elastaicSearch.bat for windows.

Once succesfully run , set the JAVA_HOME to desired value

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/64073363/406423