# Could not find java in bundled jdk running elastic search daemon

Tags: java, ubuntu, elasticsearch, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run [this](https://haystack.deepset.ai/tutorials/03_scalable_qa_system) google Colab example in a Jupyter notebook in visual code studio. (System: Ubuntu). When I try to Initialize the ElasticsearchDocumentStore, step 2 in the linked tutorial, I am getting the following error: `could not find java in bundled jdk at /home/user/Downloads/elasticsearch-7.9.2/jdk/bin/java`.

I tried to implement the top (and accepted) reply on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069739/elasticsearch-could-not-find-java-in-bundled-jdk-at-jdk-bin-java) question. Right now the `$JAVA_HOME` variable path is set correctly, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`. When I am running a Java file with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` it runs perfectly.

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin` is shown in `PATH` when I run `printenv` **BUT** when I run `echo $JAVA_PATH` I get nothing back.

When I run `java -version` I am getting this:

`openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)`